# Segmentation fault when querying Rtree retrieved from memory mapped file

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files, boost-geometry

I am quite puzzled. Consider the following code, slightly adapted from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_examples/index_stored_in_mapped_file_using_boost_interprocess.html :

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

typedef bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point; 
typedef std::pair<point, int> value_t; // **
typedef bgi::linear<32, 8> params_t;
typedef bgi::indexable<value_t> indexable_t;
typedef bgi::equal_to<value_t> equal_to_t;
typedef bi::allocator<value_t, bi::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager> allocator_t;
typedef bgi::rtree<value_t, params_t, indexable_t, equal_to_t, allocator_t> rtree_t;

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   

    std::string indexFile = "/home/jerome/proteome/index_tree.dat";
    remove(indexFile); 

    int mmfSize = 1200000;

    {
        bi::managed_mapped_file file(bi::open_or_create,indexFile.c_str(), mmfSize);
        allocator_t alloc(file.get_segment_manager());
        rtree_t * rtree_ptr = file.find_or_construct<rtree_t>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_t(), equal_to_t(), alloc);

        std::cout << "Indexing ... " << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
        {
            rtree_ptr->insert(std::make_pair(point(i,i),i*i));  
        }

        std::cout << "Indexing done." << std::endl;
    }

    {
        bi::managed_mapped_file file(bi::open_or_create,indexFile.c_str(), mmfSize);
        allocator_t alloc(file.get_segment_manager());
        rtree_t * rtree_ptr = file.find_or_construct<rtree_t>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_t(), equal_to_t(), alloc);

        std::cout << "Tree loaded, contains " << rtree_ptr->size() << " elements" << std::endl;

        // query point
        point pt(2, 1);

        std::vector<value_t> results;
        rtree_ptr->query(bgi::nearest(pt, 3), std::back_inserter(results));
        std::cout << "Query performed" << std::endl;    

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
            value_t v = results[i];
            std::cout << "Found the point " << v.second << " at a distance of " << bg::distance(v.first,pt) << std::endl; 
        }
    }

}
```

It works great. It creates an Rtree and stores it in a memory mapped file, then retrieve it and query it, no problem. However, as soon as I try to split this file in two (where the tree is built in one file, and queried in another), the queries do not work anymore! 
(The "..." in the code below refers to all the includes and typedefs from the initial example, that have been copied exactly in the two files but are removed here for clarity).

Building file:

```
...
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   

    std::string indexFile = "/home/jerome/proteome/index_tree.dat";
    remove(indexFile); 

    int mmfSize = 1200000;

    {
        bi::managed_mapped_file file(bi::open_or_create,indexFile.c_str(), mmfSize);
        allocator_t alloc(file.get_segment_manager());
        rtree_t * rtree_ptr = file.find_or_construct<rtree_t>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_t(), equal_to_t(), alloc);

        std::cout << "Indexing ... " << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
        {
            rtree_ptr->insert(std::make_pair(point(i,i),i*i));  
        }

        std::cout << "Indexing done." << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Query file:

```
...

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   

    std::string indexFile = "/home/jerome/proteome/index_tree.dat";

    int mmfSize = 1200000;

    {
        bi::managed_mapped_file file(bi::open_or_create,indexFile.c_str(), mmfSize);
        allocator_t alloc(file.get_segment_manager());
        rtree_t * rtree_ptr = file.find_or_construct<rtree_t>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_t(), equal_to_t(), alloc);

        std::cout << "Tree loaded, contains " << rtree_ptr->size() << " elements" << std::endl;

        // query point
        point pt(2, 1);

        std::vector<value_t> results;
        rtree_ptr->query(bgi::nearest(pt, 3), std::back_inserter(results));
        std::cout << "Query performed" << std::endl;    

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
            value_t v = results[i];
            std::cout << "Found the point " << v.second << " at a distance of " << bg::distance(v.first,pt) << std::endl; 
        }
    }

}
```

(The remove() is there to prevent overwriting an existing file and start fresh each time.)

The building code works fine, but the query code fails:

`Tree loaded, contains 1001 elements
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Any ideas? I expect that somehow, when the retrieval of the tree is done, something is missing so the retrieved tree is malformed and leads to memory issues when queried. But why would it happen when it's in two different files, and not when it's in the same file but in two different scopes? Shouldn't it have exactly the same behaviour?

**Edit:** I was using boost 1.54.

Comment: Woooa, lotta code here... any chance of a more succinct MCV?

Comment: @PaulEvans Given that I have really no idea what's the cause of the issue, I am unable to determine what parts of the code are definitely irrelevant, so I have to put most of it. I tried to remove redundant parts for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the R-tree can use various types of nodes, though the interface of defining and choosing them is not documented and probably will never be. In Boost 1.56 the default type of nodes was changed to variant-based exactly because of the issue you're facing.

So to use the rtree with Interprocess without problems you could:

- use a newer version of Boost, 1.56 or above (you haven't write which one you're using)
- fix your local copy of Boost by applying this simple fix: https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/commit/3474244d0a91d63752cd8a7b683fd013da030750

See also this discussion: http://boost-geometry.203548.n3.nabble.com/rtree-crash-when-used-with-inter-process-td4026037.html

At the end of the above discussion there is one more solution mentioned but it's more complicated and depends on the internals of the library. It might stop compiling at some point (in fact it should work only for Boost 1.56 and below). But if you used it, your program would require only the official Boost to compile, without any modifications.

Comment: Thanks! I was using boost 1.54 ; simply switching to 1.57  seems to solve the problem, at least in a toy example.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a doozy.

Following the code in the debugger, what actually gets stored in the nodes of the R-tree?

It turns out that the R-tree implementation stores an object of type `boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<...>`. This derives from `boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_node<...>`. This object is correctly allocated on the heap in the mapped file, storing the node data *together with the object's vtable pointer*. The vtable is instantiated once for the executable, but it's in a different location for the reader than it is for the writer. When a virtual method on the `dynamic_node` is called in the reader, the address to jump to is looked-up from the vtable address that was stored by the writer, which from the reader's point of view is somewhere in hyperspace.

And that's where the crash comes from!

There's no easy way around this: `boost::interprocess` explicitly [does not support sharing dynamic objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_region_object_limitations.virtuality_limitation).

Comment: Thanks! But isn't it a bit surprising? The boost library provides a way to store R-trees in memory mapped files, but apparently it turns out that is doesn't work for dynamic objects, and R-trees in boost are precisely that.What is the point then? Is a MMF really useful if it can be used only during one run of a program? How to use one for long-term permanent storage then? :/

Comment: Answer to my own comment : in the boost documentation, memory mapped files appear in the context of sharing data between processes, which is indeed only necessary during one run of the program. It doesn't seem designed for permanent storage, I guess.

Comment: I also think it is a shame that the R-tree implementation uses dynamic objects, as it precludes this sort of cross-process sharing using shared memory or memory-mapped files. Memory-mapped files _can_ be used for permanent storage of data in a native binary representation, but that data, as we've seen, can't have vtable pointers flying around. I don't know your ultimate application, but perhaps consider using a custom R-tree implementation?